# how can I use a email template in the following function?

Tags: python, email, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to send mail function using the following code:

```
def button_confirm_mom(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        sobj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        msg_pool = self.pool.get('mail.mail')
        cc_text = ''
        msg_vals = {
                      'subject'    : "MoM has been created",

                      'email_from' : "abc@gmail.com",
                      'reply_to'   : False,
                      'state'      : 'outgoing',
                      'model'       : False,
                      'res_id'      : False,
                      'auto_delete' : False,
            }


        if sobj.matp:
            for cc_obj in sobj.matp:
                if cc_obj.empname.work_email:
                    cc_text += cc_obj.empname.work_email + ','

        if sobj.newa:
            for cc_obj1 in sobj.newa:
                if cc_obj1.empname.work_email:
                    cc_text += cc_obj1.empname.work_email + ','
            msg_vals['email_cc'] = cc_text
        self.pool.get('mail.mail').create(cr,uid,msg_vals)
        return True
```

I wanted to know how i can use a template and send the mail for multiple people. Anyone has any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way. Add new template for mail(like view xml-file). Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="event_YOUR_ID_mail_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Name of template</field>
            <!-- for example model - res.users -->
            <field name="model_id" ref="your_module.model_res_users"/>
            <field name="email_from">test@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to" >${object.email|safe}</field>
            <field name="lang"></field>
            <field name="subject">Your subject</field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[Message of mail. <p>You can use here ${object.name} or any fields of object,</p> ]]></field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

After installing\updating your module you can find(and edit) template here: **(top menu)Settings -> (left menu) email -> template**(you must use  **developer mode** to see this menu item).

How we can use this template in python code:

```
temp = self.env.ref('your_module.event_YOUR_ID_mail_template')
if temp:
    # example: user - instance of res.users
    temp.sudo().with_context().send_mail(user.id, force_send=True)
```

Comment: Danilla Ganchar, first of all thank you very much. why the variable user.id is present in send_mail function ?

Comment: @ShravyaShetty I do not know, but I remember that in other modules every time used **ID** of record.  You can check this: `/odoo/addons/rating/models/rating.py` line **120** or `/odoo/addons/website_forum/models/res_users.py` line **79**. I work with version 9. Anyway it is work. I used this solution in my module. Hope this help you.

Comment: @Danilla Ganchar, do you have any idea on how to get your python code within the above code i have posted. wanted to just refer the email template

Comment: @ShravyaShetty If I understood what you mean... In old API it must be something like that: `def button_confirm_mom(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None): temp = self.pool.get('your_module.event_YOUR_ID_mail_template')`.

Comment: Yes it is, anyways i figured that out. Thank you very much for your answers @Danila Ganchar

Comment: do you have any idea about controller routing , opening odoo web page from email link, i have very few knowledge. do you have any reference resources except the odoo master documentatio which could be understood little easily ?

Comment: @ShravyaShetty I know that some data we can share(for example invoices) without controllers. Odoo generate link. I remember that I had problems with access for anonymous users. I have very small experience with controllers and routing in Odoo. You can create your custom controller with route and import controller in __init__  file of module/app. But how works access I don't know.